# PHP Best way to cache MySQL results?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching

I am currently building a PHP framework (original, i know) and  im working on some optimisation features for it. One dilema I have come accross is what is the best way to cache MySQL results? I know some people will say, first optimise your MySQL etc, but lets say for arguments sake, my query takes 1 minute to run and is as optimised as possible.

What would be the best way to cache the results in PHP so I dont have to rerun the query every page load?

My first thought was to maybe loop through the results, add them to an array... serialize them and then store in a file. Now as creating the cache only occurs once, I can afford the overhead of the serialize function if the array contains say 1 million results. How ever, loading the cached file and then unserializing the array on every pageload, could have performance impact.

Would it then be a better idea to while caching, instead of serializing the results and the writing to file, write to the file in a way that displays the results in a PHP readable array. So when it loads, there is no unserialize overhead.

Are there any other (read: faster) ways to cache a slow query for frequent use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If this is a straight array, then you could use [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) rather than serialize (wrapping it with the appropriate "" and write it to a .php file; then [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) that in your script. Best done if you can write it outside the htdocs tree, and only really appropriate for large volumes of data that memory caches would consider excessive.

Comment: That's a great idea, mine pales in comparison. I think I'll implement something like this in my existing homebrew solution.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it inside of the framework if you want to avoid serializing. Though I doubt there would be much overhead with serialization. Serializing will significantly reduce your cache filesize.

Answer (score 15):

[Memcached](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&biw=1024&bih=361&q=memcached&aq=f&aqi=g3g-s1g6&aql=f&oq=&fp=3e41beee0f6b4c75).

I always try to create my own solution at least once, to grasp better what's going on under the hood in most situations. When I created my own caching solution, I essentially did what you're talking about.

```
// serialize an array of all results
$serialzedData = serialize($resultData);

// set TTL (60 seconds) and create cache filename with timestamp
$ttl = 60;
$cacheFilename = $ttl . '_' . time() . '_' . md5($sqlQuery)

// dump
file_put_contents($cacheFilename, $serializedData);
```

Prior to a query firing, it would search the `cache` directory for files with a matching query hash. If it does, it tests `timestamp + ttl <= current_time`, and if true, returns the unserialized file contents. Otherwise, overwrite it.

Comment: I did pretty much this same thing just yesterday, in an effort to reduce the impact that a handful of specific queries were having but it actually ended up not helping all that much. I assume that the overhead introduced by serializing, handling the files (be it reading, writing or whatever), unserializing, etc. ended up being slow enough that it wasn't really worth doing.

Comment: The above solution might not work in the case where table updates/inserts are frequent. In real time / critical apps that needs live data than even 60 seconds won't suffice and there would be changes that old data is returned than the updated one. You could use MySQL UDF and call a php script on insert/update/delete trigger to invalidate the cache file. By this you will be sure that no old cache file resides in your directory and you may not need to use 60 seconds time. The UDF and trigger can be a way to go...

Comment: Absolutely @SURFER-TM, the naïve example is only to help grasp the cache workflow. Today, I go with a combination of ad-hoc memoization (where applicable) and Redis for the longer TTL backing store.

Comment: Do give a try to MySQL UDF and triggers. You will definitely like it...

Answer (score 4):

Mysql caches result of query, may be you should increase mysql query cache size? Or cache result of big query in standalone table?

Answer (score 3):

Google for Memcache, that should put you in the right direction.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that memcache is a compiled library that needs to be installed on the server beforehand? If so, i cant expect everyone who uses the framework to have it installed :/

Comment: There is also APC which may be easier to use as it's a PHP module that does not require an external application. Though I am sure performance is not as good.

Comment: Or redis, but people are less likely to have access to redis than to memcache or APC

Comment: @adam-peck APC is often faster than memcache, because it doesn't need to make a request from an (external) server, so no network latency

Comment: APC is used to cache php bytecode so the interpreter isn't invoked. You can't make a statement that APC is faster than Memcache, because you omitted the way both of them work. @Ozzy - yes, Memcache doesn't have to be installed at target machine. However, it is the _best_ way to cache MySQL results on commodity servers (there are other ways tho, such as dumping entire MySQL dataset in the memory and then using HandlerSocket so you access InnoDB data directly via primary key, which requires a monster machine).

Comment: Memcache and APC are not comparable. The achieve two different goals.

Comment: If you can't expect people to have memcache or apc installed, then you probably can't expect them to have write access via php either. Lots of shared servers don't give php write access.

Comment: MySQL has a limit of 1MB of data per key. It may not be the best solution for queries that return a lot of data.

Comment: useless answer. see FAQ. -1