# PHP caching sql results

Tags: php, mysql

I have some mysql queries that fetch data from database, the results will not change in 24 hours and i want to store in cache, how to cache results for 24 houre and recache them after expire houre?

```
<?php
$getTopics=$db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT * ,  categories.title AS category_title, 
                                        status_topics.title as status_topic
                                        FROM contents
                                        JOIN categories ON categories.id = contents.category
                                        JOIN status_topics ON status_topics.id = contents.status "));

$getCategories           = $db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM categories"));
$getTags                 = $db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM status_topics"));
$getPages                = $db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM pages"));
$getSiteInformation      = $db->loadRow($db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM settings JOIN categories"));
$getSubDomainInformation = $db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM sub_domains"));
$getUserInformation      = $db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM users"));
?>
```

Comment: how about searching for `mysql query cache` in google?

Comment: Memcached can do this for you. Here is a very similar question that should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327160/php-best-way-to-cache-mysql-results

Answer (score 6):

A very simple, database-free caching mechanism:

```
$filename = 'cache.txt';
if (filemtime($filename) < time()-24*3600) { //older than a day
  /*get your data*/
  file_put_contents($filename, serialize(array($getCategories, $getTags, [...])); //your data in a serialized form
} else {
  $data = unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));
  list($getCategories, $getTags, [...]) = $data;
}
```

(Obviously you should replace [...] with your variables holding your data)

Answer (score 1):

By default mysql cahche queries and perform faster when the samre results are retrieved, you can also tell mysql to cache results in the memory.

for e.g.

```
$getCategories = $db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM categories"));
```

cached remains in the memory till server restart or you force to clear the memory.

```
$db->query("RESET QUERY CACHE;");
```