# Reset mysqli cache on a per-query basis

Tags: php, mysql, caching

Refering to :

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php

[PHP Best way to cache MySQL results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327160/php-best-way-to-cache-mysql-results)

[PHP caching sql results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806537/php-caching-sql-results)

From my undestanding i can make a query get cached on the fly by adding

```
"/*" . MYSQLND_QC_ENABLE_SWITCH . "*/ "."SELECT ...
```

in front of my query (example 1 of php.net links above).

**The question is, can i do the same, meaning, ask the server to 'reload' the cache on the fly with a single QUERY ?**

one answer on SO says i can reset the cache by using

```
$db->query("RESET QUERY CACHE;");
```

But this would need an extra call, and i don't necessary want to clear ALL the cached result.

Im doing a select to fecth configuration setting for my platform but i don't want to make a select call for every request (image, json, ajax, etc) so i would cache the results on the 1st request from the client and then use the cached setting for subsequent request. Query will reset cache  when a new session start from the client and there a monitoring system to send the user out if a setting change (aka maintenance==true) or the session expired, etc.. so no worries.

That's just one case scenario where i can take advantage of being able to cache and reload cache on the fly. I didn't test anything yet, i just want to know if it is doable before i start digging in the code to patch it up and add 99 bugs at the same time ;)

- i am using mysqli (prepared statement for the most but not exclusively) and NOT PDO.
- i am not using any framework,
- on PHP 5.4.16, centOS 7 and mariaDB 5.5.52 for dev
- CentOs 6, php 5.4.1 with MySQL 5.5.52 in prod.

PRECISION: want/need a query that will, flush cache for this particular query (not all cache), run the query, cache the new results and return the results.

After studies, i found out that http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqlnd-qc.php could come at help.

Comment: indeed, thanks to the link provided by Your comon sense, we can conclude that RESET QUERY CACHE will reset all the cache and that is not what i expect.

Comment: i think this can be close to my reality: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqlnd-qc-set-cache-condition.php

Answer (score 2):

I fell that you are looking for the [SQL_NO_CACHE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html) modifier:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE FROM table
```

will give you a non-cached result

Comment: will it recache the resulst or just skip the cached result? Also i have found this but there no documentation/example. MYSQLND_QC_TTL_SWITCH (string) SQL hint used to set the TTL of a result set. Maybe by setting the cache TTL to 0 will reset the cache?

Comment: as per your link it does not recache it "...nor does it cache the query result." But thats a step ahead.

Comment: I took your question as a "per query basis" - so it does

Comment: maybe it was misleading but i wanted to make a query that will, flush cache for this particular query, run the query, cache the new results and return the results. Will add the precision to my answer.